# imgAreaSelect - selecting the same area in multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, and I am trying to use a jQuery plugin called [imgAreaSelect](http://plugins.jquery.com/imgareaselect/)! the documentation is [here](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html)

I have two different images (in same size) to work on: image1 and image2. What I want to do with this plugin is to select an area from image1, while showing the selected area on image2. I wrote a code below to select an area from image1 and show the same selected are on image 2. However, I can only select area on image 1 and 2 separately -- they are not synced. How can I sync the selection?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#image1').imgAreaSelect({ 
        handles: true, 
        onSelectEnd: function(img, selection){
            $('#img1_x1').val(selection.x1);
            $('#img1_y1').val(selection.y1);
            $('#img1_x2').val(selection.x2);
            $('#img1_y2').val(selection.y2);
        } 
    });
    var ias = $('#image2').imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
    ias.setSelection(
        val(selection.x1),
        val(selection.y1),
        val(selection.x2),
        val(selection.y2),
        true
    );
    ias.setOptions({ show:true });
    ias.update();
});
```

What can I do to display the selection area (dashed rectangle) on image2 at the same position? It would be the best if a user can adjust the size of selected area on image2 as well, and see the changed area on image1.

Please help me!

Comment: Did you look at any of the existing questions to see what you could figure out? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imgAreaSelect

Comment: I could not find an existing question that addresses this problem.. Maybe I am missing something really simple.